# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object

Tags: node.js

For

```
const systemRegex = /^system\./,
  endOfLine = require('os').EOL,
  EJSON = require('mongodb-extjson');
```

I got error at the line `EJSON = require('mongodb-extjson')`, details is as follows:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received function hidden
    at Function.from (buffer.js:331:9)
    at fnv1a32 (/hdd/all_nlus/nlu_platform_bundle/backend/node_modules/mongodb-extjson/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/fnv1a.js:21:25)
    at fnv1a24 (/hdd/all_nlus/nlu_platform_bundle/backend/node_modules/mongodb-extjson/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/fnv1a.js:39:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/hdd/all_nlus/nlu_platform_bundle/backend/node_modules/mongodb-extjson/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:14:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/hdd/all_nlus/nlu_platform_bundle/backend/node_modules/mongodb-extjson/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/bson.js:7:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: What version of Node do you use? I cannot reproduce this issue when I paste those three lines of code. I'm using `v10.15.3`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek nodejs as v12.18 with mongodb-extjson@3.0.3

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the Node.js version.

- Node.js v10.15.1: Works!
- Node.js v12.8.1: Error loading the module

I am not sure about the cause, but I would guess that it is because Node.js' packaging mechanism has undergone a change. And `mongodb-extjson` has not been modified to adhere to the new mechanism. As mentioned in their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-extjson), it is unlikely to be fixed as it is no longer being maintained.

You have the following choices:

1. Downgrade to v10 of Node.js, OR
2. Use the recommended [bson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson) module instead:

```
$ npm install bson
```

```
const { EJSON } = require('bson');

const data = '{ "someId": { "$oid": "5ec7cb151a1878fbefce4119" } }'
const doc = EJSON.parse(data, { relaxed: false });

console.log(doc.someId._bsontype)
// Should print 'ObjectID'
```

Note the difference in the EJSON option between the two modules. Whereas in `mongodb-extjson` the default is `strict`, in `bson` the default is `relaxed`.